# Linker command fail, exit code 1 with Flurry

Tags: swift, analytics, linker-errors, exit-code, flurry

When I import Flurry as per the instructions here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios/

I get the following error after following all the instructions and trying to run:

[image]

I have tried the following after much research:

1. Check my Compile Source in Build Phases - all was OK
2. 'Clean'and re-run - Nothing
3. Deleting and re-importing - No Good
4. Checking to see if my riding header is exposed in Build Settings - all was OK

The weird thing is when I create a brand new project and follow the same steps I don't get the same error and the build compiles and runs just fine.

Any ideas please!

Here is the long blurb:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

1. Remove and 'move to trash' all Flurry files including bridging header
2. In Build Phases -> 'swift compilers'....delete the reference to your old bridging header
3. Drag and Drop FLurry files wanted but DO NOT PUT THEM INTO YOUR PROJECT FOLDER. Put them outside your project folder into their own file.
4. Add bridging header and #import "Flurry.h"

Use as normal